# How can I make sure a program didn't install malware?

Tags: logging, malware, sudo

I have a program that I need to run as sudo.  I think I trust it, but I want to be sure it's not doing anything funky.  Is there a way to see what files it changes or creates with a log or something?

I'm on ubuntu gnome 17.04

Comment: I can't think of ANY Linux software that does anything like that. I'm sure it exists but if you stick to the official Ubuntu repos you won't find any either. The closest thing will be a few that have little banner ads while they run but even those are pretty rare on Linux.

Comment: The way security analysts do this is by using a virtual machine that records various activities like all calls to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

As jdwolf mentioned in a comment, a virtual machine that logs all file access would be a robust solution. Even if the malware can detect it's running on a VM, that's a pretty normal thing today. And if the VM seems slow, it may just be because the virtualization platform happens to be under a heavy workload.

It is also possible to run a program through `strace` or similar debugging command, which records all system calls made by the program. However, a clever malware author can make their malware detect when it is run under any sort of debugging functionality (like `strace`). Then the malware could behave innocuously that time and leave the bad stuff until later, when it's not run under debugging tools.